# How to QuickBlox cloudcode?

Tags: quickblox

How I make custom cloudcode on QuickBlox ?
I found https://github.com/soulfly/QuickBlox-cloudcode but how can I pass parameters to cloud ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBlox doesn't provide an ability to upload custom code to the cloud.

It's just my temporary workaround how to do it, but it's now finished yet.

Here is how it can work:

1) Use QuickBlox Web SDK to write some code on javascript http://quickblox.com/developers/Web .
Here is an example of simple script which creates session, get custom objects and return to user https://github.com/soulfly/QuickBlox-cloudcode/blob/master/Web/qb_cloudcode_demo.html

2) Upload this file to QuickBlox Content module, use Admin panel

3) Use public url of this file and load it in mobile app in WebView. It will perform all your custom code and render result. You just need to extract this final result and use in application.

That's all, I will try to finalise it soon, but you also can do it